# Selecting rows with occurences of text in any tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using PHP with MySQL. I have two tables:

Table 1 - 3 columns: ad_id, title, content
Table 2 - 2 columns: ad_id, location

Now how can I perform search e.g. for "accountants in paris" so it will return rows only if "accountants", "in", and "paris" is located somewhere in any of the columns. E.g. if tables contain:

Table 1:

```
ad_id=1
title="blah"
content="accountants"
```

Table 2:

```
ad_id=1
location="in paris"
```

I will get a row

```
ad_id title location
1     blah  in paris
```

Because "accountants in paris" is in any of the columns for this particular ad_id. Same result would be if:

Table 1:

```
ad_id=1
title="in"
content="paris"
```

Table 2:

```
ad_id=1
location="accountants"
```

However if tables are:

Table 1:

```
ad_id=1
title="blah"
content="accountants"
```

Table 2:

```
ad_id=1
location="paris"
```

I should return no rows because "paris" is missing. Is this possible with mySQL at all? Or would I have to run 3 separate queries and track results somehow in php?

BTW apologies if my explanation is confusing, I found it quite difficult to explain for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The capability that you are looking for is full text search.  The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) in MySQL is pretty thorough on the subject.

You can create a full-text index on multiple columns, which seems to be the capability that you are looking for.  Plus it is much faster (in general) than searching for each term individually.

One caveat about your particular search.  The word `'in'` is a stop word, so it would be ignored by default.  Also, words shorter than 4 characters are ignored by default.  Both of these can be modified, but this is a heads up if you try to build such an index.